# How to plot a colored surface in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have a set of data (x,y,z,w), e.g.

```
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 3.295487e-03 1.628957e-02
0.000000e+00 1.010101e-02 4.637040e-03 1.627804e-02
0.000000e+00 2.020202e-02 6.393257e-03 1.625705e-02
0.000000e+00 3.030303e-02 8.637018e-03 1.622050e-02
0.000000e+00 4.040404e-02 1.143315e-02 1.615969e-02
```

And I want to plot a colored surface like https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html

But with the colormap reflecting the magnitude of w instead of z.
Any advice?

Comment: As well as the duplicated, see also this example which uses the `facecolors` kwarg: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d_3.html

Comment: thank you. i should have a more attentive search before asking.